# Is it possible to use string act as json key?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use string act as json key?

Something like this. Many thanks.

```
var json=await fetch(abc.com) // a json is returned
var justARandomString='jbbwjvbj' // Assume whatever the string value is
var val=json.justARandomString // justARandomString is the variable declared in line 2, but not the key name itself
```

Comment: There's nothing related to JSON in your question. Don't use JavaScript objects with JSON.

Comment: `await fetch(abc.com)` doesn't return json.